# Building a multidimensional array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I'm trying to build up a multidimensional array which will hold two bits of info for each record in a database e.g. id, description.

This is what I am currently doing.

```
Dim mArray(,) As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
While cmdReader.Read()
    mArray(i,0) = cmdReader.Item("id")
    mArray(i,1) = cmdReader.Item("description")
    i = i + 1
End While
```

The problem I have here is that it doesn't like the `i` in `mArray(i,0)`. Anyone have any ideas about this? This is the error that is given `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Thanks for any and all help.

Nalum

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not rather make use of [List Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and [Dictionary Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

You can rather then create a List of Dictionaries, with the key and value both strings. The key can then represent your key (id and description in your example, and the value can be what ever was stored).

Something like

```
Dim values As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))()
```

and then in the while loop something like

```
values.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From { _
    {"id", cmdReader.Item("id")} _
})
values.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From { _
    {"description", cmdReader.Item("description")} _
})
```

You could then use foreach

```
For Each value As Dictionary(Of String, String) In values
    Dim id As String = value("id")
    Dim description As String = value("description")
Next
```

Or a for

```
For i As Integer = 0 To values.Count - 1
    Dim value As Dictionary(Of String, String) = values(i)
    Dim id As String = value("id")
    Dim description As String = value("description")
Next
```

Comment: Would I then be able to loop over that using for/foreach? Don't know much about .net was thrown into it for this project.

Comment: Thanks astander, will give this a shot, looks like it will do the trick.

Comment: Took a bit of fiddling but I got it working, Thanks astander.

Comment: Any idea how to sort this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819207/how-to-sort-a-list-of-dictionary-entries-in-vb-net

Comment: For me it says `The given key was not present in the dictionary.`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
Dim mArray(1,1) As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
While cmdReader.Read()
    mArray(i,0) = cmdReader.Item("id")
    mArray(i,1) = cmdReader.Item("description")
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve mArray(i,1)
End While
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not initializing the array.

This should work, until `i` will not reach the limits set in the initialization.

```
Dim mArray(100,100) As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
While cmdReader.Read()
    mArray(i,0) = cmdReader.Item("id")
    mArray(i,1) = cmdReader.Item("description")
    i = i + 1
End While
```

But if the array limits are not known I suggest to follow [astander's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255308/building-a-multidimensional-array-in-vb-net/4255327#4255327).

Comment: Unfortunately the limits are unknown, I tired doing `Dim mArray(,2)` but was told to put a number in for the first part of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Dim values As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))()

values.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {{"quarter", q1.ToString}, {"year", y1.ToString}})
values.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {{"quarter", q2.ToString}, {"year", y2.ToString}})
values.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {{"quarter", q3.ToString}, {"year", y3.ToString}})
values.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {{"quarter", q4.ToString}, {"year", y4.ToString}})

For Each value As Dictionary(Of String, String) In values
    Dim quarter As String = value("quarter")
    Dim year As String = value("year")
    Debug.Print(quarter & "/" & year)
Next
```

Answer (score -2):

Correct it by

```
Dim mArray(,) As String = ""
```