# How do I make a multidimensional jagged array?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I am trying to make a jagged array that has,

- 3 columns
- with 5,4,4 rows respectively
- that each have 2 rows
- that have a varying number of rows, for example 6,9,5,6,4

I have the first part setup but I don't know how to get to another level of the jagged array.

```
    Dim potentialStructure()() As Short = {New Short() {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, New Short() {0, 1, 2, 3}, New Short() {0, 1, 2, 3}}
```

And how would I access an element at say, the lowest level? Thanks!

Comment: Possible Duplicate, this should be pretty easy to google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255308/building-a-multidimensional-array-in-vb-net

Comment: Jagged arrays are not the same, thanks though.

Comment: No worries, in the mean time till someone answers check out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: Thanks, still looking a more concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

I have only just spotted your question so you may have solved it by now.  If not, the following extract from something I am playing with may help.  Here I have a regular 2D array with a jagged 2D array inside.  I trust you can strip out the bits you do not need and understand the bits relevant to your requirement.

I have a structure which includes a jagged array:

```
Structure Sabc

  Dim def()() As Long
  Dim ghi As String

End Structure
```

I have a non-jagged 2D array of these structures:

```
Dim abc(,) As Sabc
```

I can calculate the required size of abc at the beginning of my program:

```
ReDim abc(sizeD1abc, sizeD2abc)
```

I can access simple variables within an element of abc easily:

```
With abc(crntD1abc, crntD2abc)
  .ghi = "Example"
End With
```

The first dimension of the jagged array always has an upper bound of 3.  I set it so:

```
With abc(crntD1abc, crntD2abc)
  .def = New Long(3)() {}
End With
```

I avoid using ReDim more often that necessary because it is an resource hungry command.  Here I initialise and step the number of elements by 10 but the values I choose depends on how big I expect the array to be and how much the actual size may vary.

```
With abc(crntD1abc, crntD2abc)
  .def(crntD1def) = New Long(9) {}
End With
crntD2def = -1
```

The following adds more elements if I need them before storing a value:

```
With abc(crntD1abc, crntD2abc)
  crntD2def +=1
  If crntD2def > UBound(.def(crntD1def)) Then
    ReDim Preserve .def(crntD1def)(UBound(.def(crntD1def)) + 10)
  End If
  .def(crntD1def)(crntD2def) = expression
End With
```

When I have finished, I discard the excess elements:

```
With abc(crntD1abc, crntD2abc)
  If crntD2def < UBound(.def(crntD1def)) Then
    ReDim Preserve .def(crntD1def)(crntD2def - 1)
  End If
End With
```