# Unlimited Array Range VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, visual-studio

I Declare an 2D Unlimited array.
My code:

```
Dim array As String(,) = New String(,) {}
        array(0, 0) = "top left"
        MsgBox(array(0, 0))
```

The problem is the msgbox shows nothing.

Comment: There is no such thing as an “unlimited array” in VB.

Comment: only please tell me how i can do this code works without an specific range?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your 2D array?

Comment: @Jonathan You can’t with the built-in array, you have to create your own class which uses e.g. a `Dictionary` internally.

Comment: @JonathanEdgardo, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255308/building-a-multidimensional-array-in-vb-net (idea Konrad brings out)

Comment: I thank you very much everyone, i will takes as an alternative type variables endless list, and also the command Redim Preserve.

They were grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the array bounds when needed with [ReDim Preserve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which copies the existing array into an array with new dimensions.

But it might be simpler to use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead, which is "unlimited" (no need to specify range, or resize manually). But a list only has one dimension. To mimick a 2D array, you could have a List of Lists (each List item is a List itself).