# multidimensional array using list class and dictionary

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

//Declaration

```
Dim values As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))()
```

I am trying to create a multidimensional array.
this is my code:

```
con.Open()
ccsfreader = ccsfcomm.ExecuteReader
ccsfreader.Read()
If ccsfreader.HasRows Then
    Do
        values.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {{"CostCentre", ccsfreader.Item("CostCentre")}})
        values.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {{"ProcessDescription", ccsfreader.Item("ProcessDescription")}})
    Loop While ccsfreader.Read()
End If

con.Close()

For Each value As Dictionary(Of String, String) In values
    Dim CostCentre As String = value("CostCentre")
    Dim ProcessDescription As String = value("ProcessDescription")
    cmblaborcost.Items.Add(CostCentre)
Next
```

My error is:
The given key was not present in the dictionary.

i want an output like this:

```
1 => array(
CostCentre=>10.00
ProcessDescription=>"up"
)
2 => array(
CostCentre=>20.00
ProcessDescription=>"sided"
)
3 => array(
CostCentre=>110.00
ProcessDescription=>"cutted"
)
```

Comment: Can you show us your declaration of values, and cmblabourcost. Thank you

Comment: see the edited questions

Comment: cmblaborcost is a combo box

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: the statement after the for each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two dictionaries in the list. One of which contains only "CostCentre" key, and the other contains only "ProcessDescription" key. So when you try to access both keys from a dictionary, one key must be missing.

You may want to use `List(Of Tuple(Of String, String))` instead of `List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))`. This example works for me :

```
Dim values As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String))
values.Add(Tuple.Create("a1", "a2"))
values.Add(Tuple.Create("b1", "b2"))
values.Add(Tuple.Create("c1", "c2"))

'generate array from List of Tuple'
Dim result = values.Select(Function(x) New String() {x.Item1, x.Item2}).ToArray()
For Each s As String() In result
    Console.WriteLine(s(0) & ", " & s(1))
Next
```

And for your case, it could be something like this :

```
'example to add item to list'
Dim values As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String))
......
If ccsfreader.HasRows Then
    Do
        'values.Add(Tuple.Create(ccsfreader.Item("CostCentre"), ccsfreader.Item("ProcessDescription"))'
        values.Add(New Tuple(Of String, String)(ccsfreader.Item("CostCentre"), ccsfreader.Item("ProcessDescription")))
    Loop While ccsfreader.Read()
End If

.......
'example to access item from list'
For Each value As Tuple(Of String, String) In values
    Dim CostCentre As String = value.Item1
    Dim ProcessDescription As String = value.Item2
    cmblaborcost.Items.Add(CostCentre)
Next
```

Comment: i just follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255308/building-a-multidimensional-array-in-vb-net

Comment: im using vb 2010. .NET 4.5.1

Comment: okay, I'm not sure how it was working in the post you linked to. Anyway, since `Tuple` if already available in .NET version you're using, I post an alternative using list of `Tuple`, this approach works fine for me here.

Comment: thank you har07 but i have an error of this :Value of type 'System.Tuple(Of Object, Object)' cannot be converted to 'System.Tuple(Of String, String)'

Comment: hmm.. Seems that it is inferred wrongly as `Tuple(Of Object, Object)`. Try to create the tuple using explicit type declaration : `New Tuple(Of String, String)(value1, value2)`

Comment: i solve this using this code:
Dim a as string =ccsfreader.Item("CostCentre")
Dim b as string =ccsfreader.Item("ProcessDescription")
        values.Add(New Tuple(Of String, String)(a, b))
thank har0

Comment: sir last question can I put value.Item3 ? in for each

Comment: sir is this standard? Dim values As New List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, String, Integer, Integer, String))

Comment: I think that's fine. You can store up to 8 values in tuple : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)